# Indexing on datatype date vs datetime

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm indexing a table and had a quick question.

Is there a benefit when writing to a table if the indexed-column is a datatype of date rather than datetime?

Comment: Date or datetime really depends on the data you are storing. If you don't need/have a *time* component, use `date`. An index will support any query that is sargable and can use it.

Comment: Only the size, I think. But you should only use `datetime` if you actually have time components

Comment: The field is call_time so it has a date and time but when querying we're going to specifically check to see if a call came in today

Comment: Then you want the column to be a date and time data type (`datetime`, `datetime2`, etc), not a `date`, @kraphty23 . Then, when you query your data, you ensure you use proper date boundaries. Such as `WHERE call_time >= '20210712' AND call_time < '20210713'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes its better to use type date. Its a smaller type and more keys can fit into a page and therefor its if you have millions of records it will operate faster.